# Python Eel : How to set User Interface (UI) to full screen when executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, eel

I have been trying to set my GUI to full screen when executed but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

My code --

```
import eel
import io
import sys

stream = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream
sys.stderr = stream


eel.init(".")
@eel.expose
def python():
    pass


eel.start("home.html", size= (500,500))
```

I will be using pi installer to make the .exe file. Additionally, i have tried to use

```
eel.start('home.html', mode='chrome', cmdline_args=['--kiosk'])
```

but this doesn't work. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

eel.start("home.html", cmdline_args=["--start-fullscreen"])

Comment: Hi. Thankyou for the response. I tried this. Doesn't work